# Perl class::dbi - multiple connections

Tags: perl, class-dbi

I have a class library I have developed over the last few years that uses Perl's Class::DBI to wrap a relational database (the DB scheme for Prestashop, not that that matters)

Is anyone aware of anyway in a single perl script to create multiple "instances" of this class, pointing to different database?  E.g. now I do something like:

```
use MyClassLib;
MyClassLib->connection('dbi:mysql:mydatabase', 'username', 'password');
MyClassLib->some_method()
```

All that works nicely.

What I'm trying to do is essentially alias `MyClassLib` to be able to use another "instance" of it pointing at a different database.  Which is a pain as `Class::DBI` stores its database connection as static state.

Something like this in pseudo code

```
use MyClassLib;
use MyClassLib as MyClassLibAlias;
MyClassLib->connection('dbi:mysql:mydatabase', 'username', 'password');
MyClassLibAlias->connection('dbi:mysql:mynewdatabase', 'username', 'password');
MyClassLib->some_method()
```

And then from code access `MyClassLib` and `MyClassLibAlias`.  Im aware `Class::DBI` is legacy and a solution that uses `DBIx::Class` would also be appreciated if non exists for `Class::DBI`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Class::DBI` [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~tmtm/Class-DBI-v3.0.17/lib/Class/DBI.pm#Dynamic_Database_Connections_/_db_Main) tell you to provide your own `db_Main()` method in lieu of using `connection()`. I believe this could return a standard DBI handle, but Class::DBI uses Ima::DBI internally. You could use a single class for this, but to mirror your pseudo code:

```
package MyClassLibAlias;
use base qw(MyClassLib);

sub db_Main {
    my $self = shift;        
    my ($dsn, $username, $password) = ...;
    return Ima::DBI->connect_cached($dsn, $username, $password);
}
```

You'll likely want to reference the dsn, username and password using class attributes.